# How to iterate through files and save transformations applied using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on my first real personal project using python where I use edge detection to create a "scanned" image and eventually convert the scanned images into a pdf. So I was able to get my scan image code working on a single file but I tried using a for loop over the files in the directories but it does not seem to save each scanned image. It saves only the first one. However, it is evident due to my console logs that the for loop is completing. I can't seem to figure out where the file isn't changing. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
# import packages
from pyimagesearch.transform import four_point_transform
from skimage.filters import threshold_local
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import glob




# Iterate through file and make them into scanned versions
for filepath in glob.iglob('images/*.jpg'):

    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
    orig = image.copy()
    image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)


    # convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
    # in the image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

    # show the original image and the edge detected image
    print("Applying Edge Detection")
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.imshow("Edged", edged)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # find the contours in the edged image, keeping only the
    # largest ones, and initialize the screen contour
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

        # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
        # can assume that we have found our screen
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = approx
            break

    # show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
    print("Finding contours of pages")
    cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Outline", image)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
    # view of the original image
    warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)

    # convert the warped image to grayscale, then threshold it
    # to give it that 'black and white' paper effect
    warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    T = threshold_local(warped, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
    warped = (warped > T).astype("uint8") * 255

    # show the original and scanned images
    print("Applying perspective transform")
    cv2.imshow("Original", imutils.resize(orig, height = 650))
    cv2.imshow("Scanned", imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))

    # Save scanned image

    page_num = 1

    print("Saving scanned image")
    cv2.imwrite('scanned' + str(page_num) + '.jpg', warped)
    page_num += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the

```
page_num = 1
```

before

```
for filepath in glob.iglob('images/*.jpg'):
```

Else it will be `1` on every `cv2.imwrite`:

> ```
> # Iterate through file and make them into scanned versions
> for filepath in glob.iglob('images/*.jpg'):
>
>     # <<< SNIPP lots of code >>>
>
>     page_num = 1   # this will reset it to 1 _every single time_
>
>     print("Saving scanned image")
>     cv2.imwrite('scanned' + str(page_num) + '.jpg', warped)
>     page_num += 1
> ```

Comment: That makes so much sense, thank you so much. For some reason it just slipped me.